# How to call external Groovy files from Jenkins Build Flow Plugin script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

A JobDSL script can use a Groovy file in the same directory. For example, `Git.groovy` with contents like:

```
class Git extends Closure<Void> {
  final String git

  def Git(final String git = '/usr/bin/git') {
    super(null)

    this.git = git
  }

  def call(ArrayList<String> command, File dir = null) {
    final gitCommand = [git, *command].execute(null, dir)
    gitCommand.waitFor()
  }
}
```

can be used by a JobDSL script:

```
final git = new Git()
git(['clone', ...])
```

But when the same thing is tried in a Build Flow script, it emits something like:

```
Script1.groovy: 49: unable to resolve class Git
```

This happens even if the Build Flow script has `Flow run needs a workspace` set.

How can a Build Flow script re-use common code?